# API Call header issue with Accept element using SQL procedures using API Consumer by geral2 on GitHub

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to make a call to a RESTful API using a project developed by [geral2](https://github.com/geral2/SQL-APIConsumer) on GitHub.

The project is to provide abilities to call an API from a SQL Server stored procedure.

The problem I am having is with the header, specifically with the `Accept` element. The error I am getting is this:

> The 'Accept' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.  Parameter name: name

I am trying to make an API call to UPS to get package tracking information.

From the UPS Tracking RESTful Developer Guide:

METHOD: `GET`

Header elements:

```
transId: 12345
transactionSrc: TestTrack
Username: user name
AccessLicenseNumber: accesslicensenumber
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
```

URL: https://wwwcie.ups.com.ups.com/track/v1/details/1Zxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?locale=en_US

My stored procedure code:

```
DECLARE @httpMethod nvarchar(max) = 'GET'
DECLARE @URL nvarchar(max) = 'https://wwwcie.ups.com/track/v1/details/1Z5338FF0107231059'
DECLARE @Headers nvarchar(max) = 
      '[{
              "Name":       "TransId",
              "Value"       :"12345"
       },
       {      "Name":       "transactionSrc",
              "Value"       :"TestTrack"
       },
       {
              "Name":       "Username",
              "Value"       :"Myusername"
       },
       {
              "Name":       "AccessLicenseNumber",
              "Value"       :"MyAccessCode"
       },
       {
              "Name": "Content-Type",
              "Value" :"application/json"
       },
       {      "Name": "Accept",
              "Value": "application/json"
       }]';
 
DECLARE @JsonBody nvarchar(max) = ''
 
DECLARE @ts AS TABLE 
               (
                   Json_Result nvarchar(max),
                   ContentType varchar(100),
                   ServerName varchar(100),
                   Statuscode varchar(100),
                   Description varchar(100),
                   Json_Headers nvarchar(max)
               )
 
DECLARE @i AS INT 
 
INSERT INTO @ts
 
EXECUTE @i = [dbo].[APICaller_Web_Extended] 
                        @httpMethod, @URL, @Headers, @JsonBody
 
SELECT * FROM @ts
```

Please let me know if there is any other information that would be needed.

I would appreciate any suggestions anyone would provide.

Thank you

Greg

Comment: geral2's APIConsumer code already has special case handling to apply the Content-Type values to the [HttpWebRequest.ContentType property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.contenttype). Seems like it would need similar special case handling to apply the Accept values to the [HttpWebRequest.Accept property](https://github.com/geral2/SQL-APIConsumer/issues). Have you tried logging a feature request asking for such?

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is new to me so I didn't really know what was missing. I will post a request for the feature.